# What's the best way to connect a 4-digit 7-Segment LED to Atmega168

Tags: arduino, 7segmentdisplay, atmega

I'm working on a device with a 4-digit 7-segment counter and wondering what is the best way to drive all the LEDs. Right now I have a custom PCB that's driving them all from an Atmega168, using most of the I/O pins. The problem is that some of the numbers appear brighter than others. For example, a "1" is brighter than an "8888".
Someone suggested that should be using an LED driver such as the TLC5940.

Is this necessary? Since it's for a wearable device, I'm trying to keep the size and power to a minimum.

The current prototype works well, but I want to make sure the digits are equally bright and as bright as they can safely be, to increase it's visibility.

Comment: I removed your header and the signature (per [this guideline](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029/146495)) and fixed the formatting at '"888".\nSomeone...' If you want people to know your name, add it to your profile [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/edit/4101) and it will appear, with your [gr]avatar, at the bottom-right of your posts. Good question, though!

Answer (score 2):

You can reduce the number of pins you are using on the AVR by multiplexing the displays. Connect all the segments together and connect them to seven output pins via resistors, and connect the four common cathodes to another four output pins. This should give you consistent brightness. The software will be more complex, but it's a much better solution.

Because the human eye responds to peak brightness, multiplexing can provide more brightness than is possible with non-multiplexed displays, and uses less power, especially if the duty cycle is reduced.

You need to ensure that the current limits of the AVR pins aren't exceeded, of course. Driver devices will be needed if greater currents than the 25 mA limit for the AVR pins are required. I use them on a PCB I designed for a similar application.

Comment: That will reduce the intensity, though, as you only have a 25% duty cycle for each individual display.

Comment: That is fixed by putting more current through the displays, by using lower value segment resistors. Because of the low duty cycle, high currents are possible, increasing the brightness as much as necessary, without wasting power.

Comment: I think this is what I'm doing now, multiplexing. I have segments A – G on pins 11 – 19 (skipping 13). And digit 1 - 4 on pins 7 - 10. This works fine except for the brightness issue. The 8888 should be brighter or the 1 should be dimmer, preferably the former so it's nice and bright. Thanks for the feedback though.

Comment: Do you have resistors for the segments?

Comment: @Leon Heller. I had 60 ohm resistors, but replaced them with 3ohm to try to increase brightness It made everything a little brighter, but the 1 is still too hot. Do I need an LED driver, or could I get away with a cheaper part like a 74HC595 shift-register or I2C I/O expander?

Comment: 3R is far too low, and is causing the brightness variation.

Comment: Thanks Leon. My board is running at 3V3 and the LEDs are specced at 2V1, does this mean I should have 120 ohm resistors for each of the segments(7) and digits(4)? Or just the segments OR digits?

Comment: Assuming that you are switching on the digits one after another for multiplexing, you need the 120 Ohm resistors on the segments. The value would be right, as you are only allowed 100mA for all the pins on one port, see the notes on 28.2. DC Characteristics in the data sheet. You are exceeding the limits by far.

Comment: With 3 Ohm = 400mA at 1.2V you are exceeding the absolute limit of 40mA per port pin by far, the ATmega168 could take damage.

Comment: @starblue, I don't think the mega will be damaged, the current will just limit at 40mA.

Comment: @vicatcu: Wrong. AVR IO ports are *not* current limited, like almost every microcontroller. Increasing the current too far will cause internal heating of the chip, which will eventually lead to failure.

Answer (score 1):

You don't *need* a LED driver, but it has its advantages. You save a lot on your microcontroller's I/O, you only need a couple of lines for the serial interface (SPI or I2C). It may also save board space, since you don't need a bunch of discrete components for the multiplexing.
Personally I like the [Maxim MAX6950/51](http://datasheets.maxim-ic.com/en/ds/MAX6950-MAX6951.pdf) for five and eight 7-segment digits resp. It comes in a small 16 pin package. It has digital brightness control and hexadecimal-to-7-segment decoder. Interfaces to your uC with 3 lines.

Comment: TSOP package isn't easy to solder by hand! The MAX7221 exists in DIL package.

Comment: @Federico - well, if you want to save space, you have to suffer! :-). The MAX6950 package is only 5x5mm! BTW, if you want the 7221 because of better solderability you can still choose the SOIC package.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying that this is a wearable device. It is possible that the brightness problems you're seeing have nothing to do with the chip(s) involved, but is a result of the internal resistance of the battery, especially if you're using button cells. I.e., when you're trying to turn on all LEDs (in a segment) at once, you hit the limit of how much current the battery can deliver, regardless of the microcontroller's drivers.

Answer (score 0):

A viable approach is to use a chain of four 8-bit shift registers (e.g. 74HC595) to drive all the segments, and use the same size current limiting resistor for each segment (important - each segment gets its own resistor).

Then just shift in the appropriate 32-bit pattern from the AVR for the value you are trying to depict. That will decouple the power requirements of the LCD from the AVR pin current sourcing constraints. It will also reduce your AVR pin utilization to three pins (data, clock, latch).

In terms of software complexity, all you need is a table to map digit values to bit patterns. If you keep the wiring consistent among digits, that's just a 10-entry lookup table (if you are just displaying plain-old base-10 numbers). The shift register communication protocol couldn't really be much simpler - open the latch, clock in the data bits, close the latch, and they are capable of reliable operation at speeds far greater than you can achieve with AVRs, so you can just wiggle the wires as fast as possible in software. If you want to reduce power, you can conceivably achieve PWM by shifting in 0x0000 during the off cycle as well and using timer interrupts to ensure duty cycle consistency for example.

Last thing, these things are cheap and come in DIP packages if that is important to you.